# Converting CSS to styled component issue

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am new to styled components. In my React code I have some conditional rendering to change some CSS depending on if I scroll my navbar with the following code:

```
const [colorChange, setColorchange] = useState(false)
const changeNavbarColor = () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 80) {
      setColorchange(true)
    } else {
      setColorchange(false)
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("scroll", changeNavbarColor)

    <nav className={colorChange ? "navbar colorChange" : "navbar"}>content</nav>
```

My problem is to write the styled component for this to work.

My normal CSS looked like this:

```
.navbar {
  /*styles...*/
}

.navbar.colorChange {
/*styles...*/
}
```

I started by creating the following with some styles:

```
const Navbar = styled.nav`
 /*styles...*/
`
```

But how do I share the styles that are common for both navbar and colorChange; I tried appending the following to the NavBar styled component:

```
const Navbar = styled.nav`
 /*styles...*/  
 .colorChange{
  /*styles...*/
 }
`
```

And then when rendering the component in React, how do I convert this line to use the styled components instead?

```
<nav className={colorChange ? "navbar colorChange" : "navbar"}>content</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass prop as dynamic value

```
const Navbar = styled.nav`
    // navbar common css
    color: ${({ color}) => color};
`

<Navbar color={colorChange ? 'red':'transparent'} />
```

as you commented you have multiple styles I suggest below approach just pass on prop for `isColorChange`

```
const Navbar = styled.nav`
  font-size: 13px; //common style
  background: ${props => (props.isColorChange ? "#6495ED" : "#2b2b2b")};
  background-color: ${props => (props.isColorChange ? "#6495ED" : "#2b2b2b")};
  margin-top: ${props => (props.isColorChange ? "10px" : "20px")};
  padding-top: ${props => (props.isColorChange ? "5px" : "10px")};
  padding-bottom: ${props => (props.isColorChange ? "5px" : "10px")};
`;

<Navbar isColorChange={true / false}></Navbar>;
```

Comment: I was not probably clear enough in my explanation. But there are a bunch of styles that .navbar and .colorChange share, not only the color, like background-color, margin-top, padding-top and padding-bottom. These are all implemented when scrolling. Otherwise, the default styles of .navbar apply.

Comment: So I created CSS string called sharedStyle for the styles that are common for NavBar and ColorChange and then implemented in both with ${sharedStyle}. 
So there a two different styled components called NavBar and ColorChange.
But how do I now implement them in my <NavBar> react component?
So, ColorChange is implemented on scroll otherwise, NavBar

Comment: I did try with the following based upon my above comments:

`<NavBar = {ColorChange ? "NavBar ColorChange" : "NavBar"}></NavBar>`

But that is not correct

Answer (score 0):

You need pass `colorChange` state to NavBar component.

This is NavBar declaration

```
const NavBar = styled.nav`
  //styled for nav bar
  color: ${props => props.color}
`
```

And use it in component

```
<NavBar color={colorChange ? '#fff':'#ddd'}>{children}</NavBar>
```